# Aggregating a raster to a coarser, existing grid -- weighting contributing pixels

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster

I have a fine-scale raster (say 30 m) and a coarse-scale raster (say 100 m). I would like to use R to resample the fine-scale raster to produce a new, coarser raster at 100 m in which the grid perfectly aligns with my existing 100 m raster (same origin and resolution). I would like the values in the new 100 m raster to reflect the average of all the 30 m raster cells that fall within it, but where each 30 m cell's contribution to the 100 m cell mean is weighted by the proportion of each 30 m cell that falls within the 100 m cell. Is there a function (and package) in R that I can use for this?

I am aware of GDAL's `gdalwarp`, but it appears to consider finer-resolution pixels as either "contributing" or "not contributing" to the coarser pixels without the possibility of partially contributing based on the percentage of the finer pixel that falls within the coarser pixel.

Another approximation is to use the `aggregate` function in the `raster` package to get as close as possible to the target resolution (in this case, an aggregation factor of 3 to yield a 90 m raster) and then sync the resulting grid to align with my existing 100 m grid using the `spatial_sync_raster` function in the `spatial.tools` package. However, this approach results in excessive smoothing and data loss relative to an approach where the raster is aggregated and synced in a single step.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @jgadoury's suggestion, I found an approach that more closely achieves my desired outcome:

1. Create a raster finer than my fine-scale raster (I used 10m) but with the same origin and extent as my coarse-scale (100m) raster and a factor of its resolution.
2. Resample the 30m raster to the 10m raster grid using `projectRaster`
3. Aggregate the 10m grid to the 100m grid using `aggregate`

The finer you make your raster in step #1, the less you smooth over local highs and lows (i.e., the less data you have contributing to a given 100m pixel from areas outside that pixel), but the less efficient the process becomes.

Comment: Have you tried using `method='ngb'` (nearest neighbour) to limit the smoothing when going from 30m to 25m? It's an appropriate technique for classification data, but it still might give good results in this context.

Comment: Yes, that approach makes sense, though it does result in greater data loss and smoothing in the final 100 m raster than the modified version of your method that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `projectRaster` function from the `raster` package

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do not see a way with 'projectRaster' to specify how all of the fine-resolution cells that fall within each coarse-resolution cell are aggregated to a single value for the coarse cell. It appears as though it only takes the value from the fine cell at the center of each coarse cell.

Comment: How about projecting your 30m grid to a 25m grid, then using aggregate with a factor of 4? Not sure if it's efficient, but worth a try

Comment: Great idea--that should do it. Thanks!

Comment: or aggregate to 90 m and then use projectRaster

Comment: Let me know if it works, I'll edit my answer and you can close the quesiton

Comment: @jgadoury, yes, it works. I created at 25m grid with the same origin and extent as my 100m grid, reprojected my 30m raster to that grid using `projectRaster`, and  the used `aggregate`  to achieve a 100m grid. This seems to cause less "smoothing" and loss of local extremes than using `aggregate` followed by `projectRaster`.